# Access Denied error when document.domain is set

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, kendo-ui

Cross post from: http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/editor/access-denied-error-when-document-domain-is-set-.aspx

I am working in an application where it is necessary to set  document.domain. This is non-negotiable. When document.domain is set and I am using localhost or a FQDM then I get an "Access Denied" error from Kendo. It has something to do with creating or accessing the iframe for the editor. The error occurs on line 301 of kendo.editor.js which is:

```
295     iframe = $("<iframe />", { src: 'javascript:""', frameBorder: "0" })
296                        .css("display", "")
297                        .addClass("k-content")
298                        .insertBefore(textarea)[0];
299     
300     wnd = iframe.contentWindow || iframe;
301     doc = wnd.document || iframe.contentDocument;
```

You can reproduce this issue by taking the editor demo (found here in the kendo download: examples\web\editor\index.html) and adding the following script tag at the end of the head:

```
<script>document.domain=document.domain;</script>
```

Setting the document.domain after the editor is initialized obviously works but probably wont always be an option. **How can I get the editor to work after document.domain is set?** Is there a way to "unset" the document.domain? Obviously I would rather not edit kendo but if there is a fix that they can add then I would open a bug for it.

I have tried setting the document.domain of the iframe via js in its source attribute to the document.domain of its parent but that didn't help.

This occurs in IE 8 & 9. The version of Kendo I am using is 2013.2.716. Let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only immediate solution is to initialize the editor from a **contentEditable** element as shown here: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/editor/inline-editing.html. Then the editor won't create an iframe.

Comment: I am setting up the editor with the .Net MVC html helper. Can you setup an inline editor with that or will I need to move to JS to configure it? Currently I don't see a way to do it with the helper.

Comment: @bygrace currently this can't be done from the MVC helper. Worth adding for a future release though.

Comment: @bygrace the problem should be now fixed.

Comment: A telerik rep told me to "modify the editor code by enforcing the _createContentElement method to always change the document.domain when initializing the iframe (remove the domain != location.hostname condition)". That worked. On 3/21/2014 we got a private email that said that they added a domain configuration so that this functionality can be configured rather than editing the source code.